# I am getting Issue of "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"?

Tags: r

I am getting problem of "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix" for long, Please help me. I am trying to find the bug  but unable to find, my data set is huge but i am using smaller initial data for program run.  I have tried my best but all in vain. The error comes in the last lines of code. I am new to coding so plz excuse my mistake in indentation.

```
########### inputs
#Y <- as.matrix(read.table("data2.dat"));
#X <- as.matrix(read.table("data1.dat"));
###########
# smaller X and Y for initial code run.
X <- matrix(c(71,22,53,14,75,68,74,93,72),9,1)
Y <- matrix(c(7,1,4,1,7,6,6,8,5),9,1)



########### Constant
Xlen <- length(X[,1])  #### rows of X
Yhat <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(Xlen,1))
error <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(Xlen,1))
Rmax <- 30
Z <- as.matrix(cbind(X,Y)) 
Zlen <- length(Z[1,]) #### columns of Z
P <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(1,Rmax))
U <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(1,Rmax)) # mu calculation
lambda <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(1,Rmax)) # lambda calculation
C <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(Zlen,Rmax))
R <- 0
sigma <- 0
beta <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(1,Zlen))
Zp <- mat.or.vec(1,Zlen)
V1 <- 0
V2 <- 0
V3 <- 0
Pz <- 0
Dmin <-0
Dind <-0
Pmax <-0
Pind <-0
r <- 0.4
alpha <- 4/(r^2)
P_mat <- 10^4 * diag(2)
gamma <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(2,Rmax))
w <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(2,Rmax))
Xe <- as.matrix(cbind(1,X))
##### 


for (i in 1:Xlen)
{   
if (i==1) 
{R <- R+1 ; C[,R] <- Z[i,] ; P[R] <- 1; Yhat <- Y[i,]}
else 

{V1 <- sum(Z[i,]^2)
sigma <- sigma + sum(Z[i-1,]^2)
beta <- beta + Z[i-1,]
V2 <- sum(Z[i,]*t(beta))
Pz <- (i-1)/((i-1)*(V1+1)+(sigma-(2*V2)))
for (j in 1:R)
{V3 <- sum((Z[i,]-Z[i-1,])^2);P[j] <- ((i-1)*P[j])/((i-2)+(P[j])+(P[j]*V3))}
dist <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(1,R))

for (k in 1:R)
{dist[k] <- abs(sqrt(sum((Z[i,]-C[,k])^2)))}


Dmin <- min(dist)
Dind <- which.min(dist)


Pmax <- max(P)
Pind <- which.max(P)


if (r > Dmin/(1-(Pz/Pmax)) && Pz > Pmax)
{C[,Dind] <- Z[i,]; P[Dind] <- Pz}

if (r < (Dmin/(1-(Pz/Pmax))) && Pz > Pmax && R< Rmax)
{R <- R+1; C[,R] <- Z[i,]; P[R] <- Pz}

for(n in 1:R)
{U[,n] <- exp(-alpha*(X[i]-C[1,n])^2)}

for(n in 1:R)
{lambda[,n] <- U[,n]/sum(U)}


A1 <- as.matrix(P_mat%*%Xe[i,]%*%lambda)
B1 <- as.matrix(t(lambda)%*%Xe[i,])
C1 <- as.matrix(diag(Rmax))
D1 <- as.matrix(P_mat)
E1 <- as.matrix(B1%*%D1%*%t(B1))
F1 <- C1+E1
gamma <- A1%*%solve(F1)
P_mat <- (diag(2)%*%gamma%*%t(lambda)%*%Xe[i,])%*%P_mat
G1 <- as.matrix(lambda%*%t(Xe[i,]%*%w))
H1 <- as.matrix(Y[i,])
I1 <- as.vector(H1-G1)
J1 <- I1*gamma
w <- w + J1; #as.matrix(I1%*%gamma)
K1 <- Xe[i,]%*%w
L1 <- lambda%*%t(K1)
```

here comes error at Yhat

```
Yhat[i,] <- L1  
#error[i,] <- Y[i,]-Yhat[i,]
#b <- b+1
}
}
#Yhat <- as.vector(Yhat)
#plot(Y,type="l",col="red")
#lines(Yhat,col="green")
#plot(Yhat)
#plot(error)
```

Comment: Figuring out on which line the error happens would be a good start...

Comment: Oh boy, the indentation style you are using is hurting me...

Answer (score 1):

Without going through all of your code, let's see what happens to `Yhat`:

First, you make it a matrix:

```
Yhat <- as.matrix(mat.or.vec(Xlen,1))
> Yhat
      [,1]
 [1,]    0
 [2,]    0
 [3,]    0
 [4,]    0
 [5,]    0
 [6,]    0
 [7,]    0
 [8,]    0
 [9,]    0
```

In the first iteration of your loop `for (i in 1:Xlen)` you assign `Y[i,]` to `Yhat`:

```
if (i==1)
{R <- R+1 ; C[,R] <- Z[i,] ; P[R] <- 1; Yhat <- Y[i,]}
```

At that point, `Y[i,]` is `7`. `Yhat` is no longer a matrix, now it's of type `numeric`. Therefore, `Yhat[i,] <- L1` throws an error.